# Ensure that there is a minimum time delay between events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I receive some data chunk-wise and want to precess the data-points with a minimum temporal distance. (You could formulate it as `throttleTime` without data loss or the opposite of `buffer`).
After a ton of trying and googling I came up with this solution:

```
dataChunkReceiver
  .pipe(
    switchMap(chunk => of(...chunk)), // spread chunk of data-points to distinct events
    zip(interval(minimumInterval)), // make sure events don't get executed more often than minimumInterval
    map(itemAndNumber => itemAndNumber[0]) // only forward the data-point
  )
```

The `zip(interval(minimumInterval))`-solution works fine with, let's say, mouse events but not in this combination with switchMap and chunks. It still works like a charm when chunks come more often than `minimumInterval` - but not if they are slower. I can't figure out why, maybe someone can enlighten me?

To see the problem [try my Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-delay-bewteen-items?file=index.ts) an set `chunkInterval`(the interval in which new chunks of data arrive) to 2000 while the `minimumInterval` is 400. As you can see, all data-points from each chunk get processed at the same time. While when you set `chunkInterval` to 400, they come out every 500 milliseconds as expected.
For 2000 as `chunkInterval` I would expect the data points at ms

```
2000 | 2500 | 3000 | 4000 | 4500 | 5000 | 6000 | 6500 | 7000
```

I am sure the must be a subtle misconception in my solution, please help to find it!

Comment: Strangely enough I didn't no stumble upon the thread containing the solution on my search, but the marked as duplicte thread does contain indeed the `2. ConcatMap to a timersolution which helped. Thanks a lot for the one finding it for me. I still do not know why my solutions fails, since it's problematic nature is mentioned but not explained int the thread - but anyway.

Comment: the `zip` approach isn't working with `chunkInterval: 2000` & `minimumInterval: 400` because the `interval` has emitted three times by the time the first chunk of 3 items gets emitted. So `zip` can zip the 3 incoming chunk items with the 3 already present interval items without having to wait for additional interval items. You can use https://rxmarbles.com/#zip to help you understand when `zip` emits. Btw. `switchMap(chunk => of(...chunk))` can be replaced with `switchMap(chunk => chunk)` which can be replaced with `switchAll()`